# How can I install Mint without a DVD?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, usb, system-installation

I am running Debian, but lack of driver support for stuff I want has made me decide to switch to Mint.  Unfortunately, I don't have a DVD and the Mint community seems to have decided I really, really need a DVD.  I have a USB, but I'm not sure how to burn the `.iso` image, rather than the file, to said USB in order to then boot from it in order to install the OS.  I'm also not convinced this is necessarily the best/simplest way to go about installing Mint.  I just want to wipe everything and get a clean install of Mint.

What do I need to do to do that without a DVD?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that mint only installs from DVD? There are easy instructions on how to make bootable USB (which can then be used for installing) that are in the top answers when you google "mint install from USB" (both created from Linux and from Windows). I have done USB installs of Mint multiple times on different machines the last few years. https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/744

Comment: @Anthon from the user guide: https://www.linuxmint.com/documentation/user-guide/Cinnamon/english_18.0.pdf

Comment: We'll that obviously shows I never read that documentation. I wasn't even aware of that document's existence. And I am typing this in Firefox running on Mint, which I have been using as desktop environment for over 3 years. Download the ISO, follow the instructions in the link and boot from the USB. You'll have the normal option from the "live" environment to install on your HD. Sorry for my doubting the documented need for DVD.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux Mint manual is far more DVD focussed than it needs to be. The ISO images for Mint are hybrid (i.e. work burnt on a CD/DVD as well as USB stick).

If you have a running Linux system, download the ISO image for the Linux Mint that you want and do:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/your/downloaded/linuxmint.iso of=/dev/sdx oflag=direct  bs=1048576
```

where you replace `x` with the drive letter of your USB (**make sure you use the right drive, otherwise you'll probably have to go reinstall from backup). the drive letter doesn't normally have a number as last part!

If you don't have a working Linux, but Windows, you'll have to install some software to transfer the ISO image to your USB. E.g [pendrivelinux](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

More information can be found in [this article](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/744) by Mint's Clem himself.

Once you have your USB reboot your machine and make sure it takes the USB drive as a boot drive (might take some BIOS twiddling). USB3.0 sticks are really fast to boot. Once you have the live system, you'll have an install to harddrive option from the menu/desktop.